# Using knockout.js, is there anyway to control the div attributes contained within a foreach

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

Here is my asp.net

```
 <div data-bind="foreach {data:movies}">
    <div class="content-item full bottom-border">
    <div class="content-item-container">
        <div class="movie-listing-header">
            <a class="icon arrow" data-bind="click: $parent.toggle"></a>

            <div class="movie-details">
                <div class="title"><a href="#" data-bind="text: MovieName, attr: { href: DetailsUrl }"></a></div> 
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="rating">
                    </div>
                    <div class="time" data-bind=" text: movieruntime "></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="icon right-arrow" href="#" data-bind="attr: { href: DetailsUrl }"></a>
        </div>         
        <div class="showtimes">    
           <div data-bind="template: { name: 'movie-grouped-showtimes-template', data: $data }"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to be able to do is simply, click on `<a class"arrow icon"`> and be able to toggle the following:

`<div class="movie-listing-header">` -- addClass(.active);
`<div class="showtimes">` -- style: block;

I can get the showtimes to work, but it adds the styling to each movie, and I want to control the toggle contained with the movie.

here is the .js

```
 function TheatreViewModel(theatre) {
        var self = this,
            initialData = theatre || Regal.userPrimaryTheatre || {},
            theatreServiceParams = {
                tmsId: initialData.TmsId,
                date: initialData.selectedDate || new Date()
            };

        self.TheatreName = initialData.TheatreName || '';
        self.PhoneNumber = initialData.PhoneNumber || '';
        self.selectedTheatreTms = initialData.TmsId;
        self.theatre = ko.observable();
        self.isLoading = ko.observable(false);
        self.selectedDate = ko.observable(initialData.selectedDate || new Date());

        self.filterFormats = [];

        self.selectedFormat = ko.observable(Regal.allFormatsFilterItem);
        self.filterFormats.push(Regal.allFormatsFilterItem);
        if (Regal.movieFormats) {
            var filtered = _.where(Regal.movieFormats, {
                Filterable: true
            });
            _.forEach(filtered, function(f) {
                f.enabled = ko.observable(false);
                self.filterFormats.push(f);
            });
        }

        self.addressText = ko.computed(function() {
            var theat = ko.unwrap(self.theatre);
            var addie;
            if (!theat || theat && !theat.Address1) {
                addie = initialData;
            } else {
                addie = theat;
            }

            return addie.Address1 + ', ' + addie.City + ' ' + addie.State + ' ' + addie.PostalCode;
        });

        self.mapEmbedUrl = ko.computed(function() {
            var a = self.addressText();
            return 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + encodeURI(a);
        });

        self.movies = ko.computed(function() {
            var thea = self.theatre(),
                mov = ko.unwrap((thea || {}).Movies),
                format = self.selectedFormat();

            if (format && format !== Regal.allFormatsFilterItem) {
                return _.filter(mov, function(m) {
                    return _.contains(_.pluck(m.formats(), 'Id'), format.Id);
                });
            }
            return mov;
        });

        self.getPerformances = function() {
            self.isLoading(true);
            Regal.loadTheatre(self.selectedDate(), self.selectedTheatreTms,
                function(data) {
                    self.isLoading(false);
                    if (data) {

                        var allFmts = _.uniq(_.flatten(_.map(ko.unwrap(data.Movies), function(mov) {
                            return mov.formats();
                        })));
                        _.forEach(allFmts, function(fmt) {
                            var filt = _.findWhere(self.filterFormats, {
                                Id: fmt.Id
                            });
                            if (filt) {
                                filt.enabled(true);
                            }
                        });
                        self.theatre(data);
                    }

                });
        };
        self.changeFormat = function(format) {
            console.log(format);
            self.selectedFormat(format);
            self.movies();

        };


        self.selectedDate.subscribe(function(newVal) {
            self.getPerformances();
        });


        self.getPerformances();






   self.toggle = function () {

        $('.showtimes').show();
        $('.movie-listing-header').addClass('.active');


}
    }

    window.Regal.TheatreViewModel = TheatreViewModel;
```

any help would be appreciated, I can't believe that this cannot be accomplished.

note: before I added knockout ... here is the jquery that was in place and working ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.icon.arrow').click(function () {
        var active_el = $(this);
        $('.movie-listing-header').each(function () {
            if ($(this).get(0) === active_el.parent().get(0)) {

                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).siblings('.showtimes').hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).siblings('.showtimes').show();
                }
                $(this).toggleClass('active');

            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).siblings('.showtimes').hide();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: what to click on? can you explain more your objective

Comment: Can you please share your JS code?

Comment: Can you add data-bind="click: ..." to the element you are referring to?

Comment: you mean the <a class="arrow icon" data-bind="click: toggle" ... yes, this works but it will not contain the style : block or style : none within the foreach

Comment: Can you paste the code of the $parent.toggle function? It's not there on the code you just pasted.

Comment: added the toggle code at the botton of the js ... thanks for any help, I can't seem to get anywhere with this... this was a non-issue when I didn't use knockout.js

Comment: That jQuery code only executes once, during load. When KO populates the bound elements, that process is independent from the jQuery code. In your case, the jQuery code is probably being executed before the KO code, which is why it isn't working.

Comment: I've found that, if I have to do things with jQuery that aren't already available as knockout bindings, it's easiest to write my own bindings.

Comment: IMO you can do one of two things: you can either migrate that logic to KO's `css` and `style` bindings, as PW Kad's answer suggests, or you can add an `afterRender` event to your KO `foreach` clause, to use a function that executes your jQuery code..

Comment: thank you all, I had no support on this from my team, the main guy who has us using knockout is not responding, but all of these are great areas to explore... I know I will find my answer ... you guys are great!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom binding handler here but a more generic way of doing it would be as such -

Use the `css` and `style` bindings to toggle the classes -

```
<div data-bind="foreach: computedMovies">
    <div class="movie-listing-header" data-bind="css: { 'active' : isActive() }, click: toggleClass">
        <div class="showtimes" data-bind="style: { 'display': isSelected() ? 'block' : 'none' }">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in your view model, create a computed to add some additional properties -

```
var computedMovies = ko.computed(function() {
    var theseMovies = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(movies(), function (movie) {
        movie.isActive = ko.observable(false);
        movie.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
        theseMovies.push(movie);
    });
    return movies;
});
function toggleClass() {
    isActive(!isActive());
}
```

**Edited with jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/gNE77/

Comment: this is making great sense ... but one question ... can I control the movie.isActive movie.isSelected with the <a class="arrow icon>

Comment: Yes just bind the click event's to some function like toggleClass

Comment: well... I am getting closer, but now I am getting an error in knockout.debug.js ...   arrayForEach: function (array, action) {
            for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++)
                action(array[i]); the error is "length" is NOT defined. 
        },

Comment: I think this will work, if I can get past this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ... any ideas

Comment: Your observableArray is undefined when it is trying to check it's length.  Either move your variable declaration above whereever you are checking length, or wrap the arrayForEach function inside a conditional statement like if (self.movies())

Comment: I am not checking the lenghth, this is being done in knockou.debug.js

Comment: ko.utils.arrayForEach tries to get the length...  Just set a debug step there and you will see that the movies observableArray is undefined at that point.  Look at the fiddle to get some ideas on how you can adjust it or start a new fiddle to demonstrate your issue